# Route not exit but still getting access?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have not route ***/home*** or ***home*** in ***routes.php*** ***but i am still able to access this route.*** It is creating problem some times during login. Sometimes when i am trying to login, after successful authenticated i am redirected this route but why because this route is not exist in  routes.php. It is also accessible as ***localhost:8000/home***. My routes.php is as follow. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
   <?php

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Application Routes
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
  | It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
  | and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
  |
 */

use Entities\Driver;
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::resource('/contact', 'HomeController@contact');

Route::post('mileage', ['as' => 'mileage', 'uses' => 'TripController@getMilesBetween']);

//Route::post('mileage', 'TripController@getMilesBetween');
Route::get('mileage', 'TripController@getMilesNotFound');

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.trip'], function () {
    Route::resource('trip', 'TripController');
}
);

Route::get('load-list', 'LoadController@showloadlist');
Route::get('load/{id}/clone', 'LoadController@cloneLoad');
Route::get('load/{id}/clone', 'LoadController@cloneLoad');
Route::get('load/{id}/attachcon', ['as' => 'load.attachcon', 'middleware' => ['auth'], 'can' => 'view.load', 'uses' => 'LoadController@attachRateCon']);
Route::get('load/{id}/attachbol', ['as' => 'load.attachbol', 'middleware' => ['auth'], 'can' => 'view.load', 'uses' => 'LoadController@attachBol']);
Route::get('load/{id}/attachments', ['as' => 'load.attachment', 'middleware' => ['auth'], 'can' => 'view.load', 'uses' => 'LoadController@attachmentList']);

Route::get('expense/{id}/attachreceipt', ['as' => 'expense.attachreceipt', 'middleware' => ['auth'], 'can' => 'view.expense', 'uses' => 'ExpenseController@attachReceipt']);
Route::get('expense/{id}/attachments', ['as' => 'expense.attachment', 'middleware' => ['auth'], 'can' => 'view.expense', 'uses' => 'ExpenseController@attachmentList']);

Route::get('maintenance/{id}/attachreceipt', ['as' => 'maintenance.attachreceipt', 'middleware' => ['auth'], 'can' => 'view.maintenance', 'uses' => 'MaintenanceController@attachReceipt']);
Route::get('maintenance/{id}/attachments', ['as' => 'maintenance.attachment', 'middleware' => ['auth'], 'can' => 'view.maintenance', 'uses' => 'MaintenanceController@attachmentList']);

Route::post('load/store-clone', ['as' => 'load.clone', 'uses' => 'LoadController@cloneStore']);


/*Invoice Routes Start*/

Route::group(['prefix'=>'invoices/'],function(){
Route::get('to_invoice','InvoiceController@LoadToInvoice');
Route::get('create/{customer_id}','InvoiceController@create');
Route::post('/store','InvoiceController@store')->name('invoice.store');
Route::get('/show','InvoiceController@show')->name('invoice.show');
Route::get('/add_payment/{id}','InvoiceController@payments');
Route::post('/store_payment','InvoiceController@store_payment')->name('invoice.payment_store');
Route::get('/pdf/{id}/{type}','InvoiceController@genratePdf')->name('pdf.invoice');
});


/*Invoice Routes end*/

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.load'], function () {
    Route::resource('load', 'LoadController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.driver'], function () {
    Route::resource('driver', 'DriverController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.contract'], function () {
    Route::resource('contract', 'ContractController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.settlement'], function () {
    Route::resource('settlement', 'SettlementController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.reexpenses'], function () {
    Route::resource('reexpenses', 'RecurringExpensesController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.mplan'], function () {
    Route::resource('mplan', 'MaintenancePlanController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.maintenance'], function () {
    Route::resource('maintenance', 'MaintenanceLogController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.invoice'], function () {
    Route::resource('invoice', 'InvoiceController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.expense'], function () {
    Route::resource('expense', 'ExpenseController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.maintenance'], function () {
    Route::resource('maintenance', 'MaintenanceController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.entry'], function () {
    Route::resource('entry', 'EntryController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.contact'], function () {
    Route::resource('contact', 'ContactController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.type'], function () {
    Route::resource('type', 'TypeController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.model'], function () {
    Route::resource('model', 'ModelController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.company'], function () {
    Route::resource('company', 'CompanyController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.vehicle'], function () {
    Route::resource('vehicle', 'VehicleController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.attachment'], function () {
    Route::resource('attachment', 'AttachmentController');
}
);

Route::group(
        [
    'middleware' => ['auth',
        'acl'],
    'can' => 'view.user'], function () {
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
}
);

Route::get('filesafe', 'AttachmentController@filesafe');
Route::get('plan-edit', 'AttachmentController@editPlan');
Route::get('attachment/download/{id}', 'AttachmentController@download');
Route::get('attachment/destroy/{id}', 'AttachmentController@destroy');

Route::get('expense/{id}/clone', 'ExpenseController@cloneExpense');
Route::post('expense/store-clone', ['as' => 'expense.clone', 'uses' => 'ExpenseController@cloneStore']);
Route::get('expense_category', 'ExpenseController@expenseCatList');
Route::get('expense_category/{id}', 'ExpenseController@expenseCatView');
Route::get('expense_category/destroy/{id}', 'ExpenseController@expenseCatDestroy');
Route::get('expense_category/{id}/edit', 'ExpenseController@expenseCatEdit');
Route::post('expense_category/update', ['as' => 'expense.catupdate', 'uses' => 'ExpenseController@expenseCatUpdate']);

Route::post('contact/mstore', 'ContactController@mstore');
Route::post('contact/mget', 'ContactController@jsonGetContact');

Route::post('type/mstore', 'TypeController@mstore');

Route::get('vehicle/{id}/{dateini}/{dateend}', 'VehicleController@show');

Route::get('trip/destroy/{id}', 'TripController@destroy');
Route::get('load/destroy/{id}', 'LoadController@destroy');
Route::get('part/destroy/{id}', 'PartController@destroy');
Route::get('entry/destroy/{id}', 'EntryController@destroy');
Route::get('contact/destroy/{id}', 'ContactController@destroy');
Route::get('type/destroy/{id}', 'TypeController@destroy');
Route::get('model/destroy/{id}', 'ModelController@destroy');
Route::get('vehicle/destroy/{id}', 'VehicleController@destroy');
Route::get('user/destroy/{id}', 'UserController@destroy');
Route::get('contract/destroy/{id}', 'ContractController@destroy');

Route::get('getModels/{entityKey}/{idType?}', 'ModelController@getModelsByType');
Route::get('getPartsByVehicle/{idVehicle}', 'PartController@getPartsByVehicle');

Route::get('sensor/download/{idPart}', 'TireController@downloadData');

Route::get('profile', 'UserController@showProfile');
Route::put('updateProfile/{id}', 'UserController@updateProfile');

Route::get('invite', 'InviteController@showInvite');
Route::put('invite', 'InviteController@storeInvite');
Route::get('create-account/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@showCreateAccount');
Route::put('create-account/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@createAccount');

Route::get('auth/social/{provider}/{token?}', 'SocialLoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'SocialLoginController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'SocialLoginController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'SocialLoginController@getLogout');

Route::post('tires/position/swap', 'TireController@positionSwap');
Route::post('tires/position/remove', 'TireController@positionRemove');
Route::post('tires/position/add', 'TireController@positionAdd');
Route::post('tires/details', 'TireController@details');
Route::get('tires/updateStorage/{vehicle_id}', 'TireController@updateStorage');
Route::post('parts/create', 'PartController@store');
Route::post('models/create', 'ModelController@storeByDialog');
Route::post('types/create', 'TypeController@storeByDialog');
Route::post('vehicle/map/updateDetail', 'VehicleController@updateMapDetail');

Route::post('vehicle/dashboard/tires', 'VehicleDashboardController@tires');
Route::post('vehicle/dashboard/localization', 'VehicleDashboardController@localization');

Route::get('vehicle/fleet/dashboard', 'VehicleDashboardController@fleet');
Route::get('vehicle/fleet/dashboard/{updateDatetime}', 'VehicleDashboardController@fleetGpsAndSensorData');
Route::get('vehicle/fleet/dashboard/{updateDatetime}/{vehicleId}', 'VehicleDashboardController@fleetGpsAndSensorData');

Route::bind(
        'users', function ($value, $route) {
    return App\Entities\User::whereId($value)->first();
}
);

Route::controllers(
        [
            'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        ]
);

/* Start Route to Delete*/

Route::get('delete',function(){
$model=Request::get('model');
$condition=Request::get('condition');
$qry=$model::find($condition)->delete();
$ret=1;
$ret2=0;
if($qry){
return $ret;
}
return $ret2;
});

/*End Route to delete*/

//Generate pdf

Route::get('/createAJAX',function(){
$model = Request::get('model');
$data=Input::all();
//unset($data['model']);
$create=$model::create($data)->id;
return $create;
});
```

Comment: use `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: ok i will try and then back

Comment: still accessing /home route. no effect

Comment: use `php artisan route:list` to see all available routes

Comment: thanks i got this route.

Comment: it is define in  vendor package

Comment: What is a package name??

Comment: its name is fleetny-web-pages https://github.com/alientronics/fleetany-web-pages

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel's authentication, then it will redirect the user to `/home` after successful login.

> When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to
>   the /home URI. You can customize the post-authentication redirect
>   location by defining a redirectTo property on the  LoginController,
>   RegisterController, and ResetPasswordController:
>
> `protected $redirectTo = '/';`
>
> If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a redirectTo method instead of a `redirectTo` property:
>
> ```
>  protected function redirectTo()
>  {
>      return '/path';
>  }
> ```

See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#included-authenticating).

You can change the route by updating `$redirectTo` prop or `redirectTo()` method in the above mentioned controllers.